# Derivation of Bernoulli's Equation considering $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$ along a streamline

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

When deriving Bernoulli's equation, $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$ for a small fluid particle is applied to streamline and the direction normal to streamline. During this operation, why is 'delta' specifically used for particle mass, volume as opposed to $d$ as in $dV$, $dxdydz$ or $dm$. Is this utilization of the Dirac delta function or something different?

see example below and notice use of delta symbol:

[image]

Comment: A source demonstrating this approach would be helpful

Comment: @electronpusher https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Derivations_of_the_Bernoulli_equation

Comment: I looked through the section where Bernoulli's equation is derived from Newton's second law, and indeed the entire article, and did not notice a single mention of $\delta$.

Comment: see update above. Thanks

Comment: This just looks like notation differences—the d and delta seem interchangeable.

Comment: Researching additional sources that’s a viable answer - still something is driving the use of the delta symbol in some instances and d in others. Curious if it is tied to the amount of elapsed time where delta t represents a greater amount of elapsed time than dt, allowing fluid element to displace further for the  interest of study?

Comment: Although often violated in text, The technically correct way to show infinitesimal change in d is using δx instead of dx, which is reserved for the derivative & integral of a function